# 'Could not extract ResultSet' error when using nativeQuery in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm using JPARepository in SpringBoot and using the `@Query` annotation but I get an error

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

When using the `nativeQuery=true`

This is my function:

```
@Query(value = "select * from table1 where status = ?1 and time <= ?2 LIMIT 2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyModel> findScheduledSmsMessages(Status status, LocalDateTime time);
```

Comment: `?1` and `?2` are incorrect for native queries. Use `?` by itself.

Comment: same result/error

Comment: Pardon me but I couldn't see what DBMS you are using, and the keyword `LIMIT` is not supported by all of them.

Comment: @Abra PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code above my query and

`@Modifying
  @Transactional`

Like this :

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM played_sheet WHERE user_id =  ?1 AND sheet_music_id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByUserIdAndSheetMusicId(Integer userId,Integer sheetMusicId);
```